# Subsets of particular values of $\zeta'(k)$ that contain irrational numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, irrational-numbers

We consider the set of elements $\zeta'(2),\zeta'(3),\zeta'(4),\zeta'(5),\ldots$ where $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function and $\zeta'(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\zeta(z)$ its derivative. Thus we consider this set and we denote it as 
$$D=\{\zeta'(k)\text{ for integers }2\leq k\}.$$ 
After we consider the power set $\mathcal{P}(D)$ and we take an element $s\in \mathcal{P}(D)$ of cardinality $|s|\geq 2$.

I would like to know if it is possible to state a similar statement than Zudilin's theorem ([1]), look at the second  paragraph of the section *Odd positive integers* from the Wikipedia [*Particular values of the Riemann zeta function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Odd_positive_integers).

Let $l\geq 1$ be an integer and $s\in\mathcal{P}(D)$ a subset with cardinality $|s|\geq 2$ of elements of $D$. Then we say that this subset $s$ has the property $W_l$ if and only if at least $l$ elements of $s$ are irrationals numbers.

> **Question.** I would like to know what work can be done to show examples of subsets $s\in\mathcal{P}(D)$  of cardinality $|s|\geq 2$ for which the property $W_l$ is true for some integer $l\geq 1$. **Many thanks.**

It is well-known the closed-form for $\zeta'(2)$ in terms of certain constants, and it is possible to get formulas for $$\lim_{z\to 2k}\frac{d}{dz}\zeta(z),$$ but I don't know if it is possible get from these an example for my Question.

I hope that my question has good mathematical content.

### References:

[1] Wadim Zudilin, *One of the Numbers $\zeta(5),\zeta(7),\zeta(9),\zeta(11)$ Is Irrational*, Russian Mathematical Surveys. **56**(4): 774–776, (2001).

Comment: I've known from a preprint on arXiv an aproach due to Ball and Rivoal (second paragraph in the first page of **arXiv:1911.08458v1** by Li Lai and Pin Yu), thus I wondered if maybe it is posible to state a similar asymptotic as $s\to\infty$ of

$$\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left(1,\zeta'(k_1),\zeta'(k_2),\ldots,\zeta'(k_{s-1})\right)\right)$$
for integers $2\leq k_1<k_2<\ldots<k_{s-1}$. I add this comment if it is a good approach to get a contribution/answer of my question.

Comment: Currently there is a version **v2** of previous arXiv mentioned in my comment. I emphasize that I'm asking about **what work can be done to show examples** (you can understand also reasonigs/heuristics concerning these examples of such subsets) in our **Question**.